# How does one add custom font-family suggestions to vscode's intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

I use vscode. In a css file (or scss or less file) when adding the font-family property to an element, it gives intellisense suggestions for various font familys to use:
[[image]

I have my small box of goto fonts for projects, and I've been looking for a way to add them to this list, in order to speed up my workflow.

I've tried adding custom emmet snippits, but this, from what I've attempted, only allowed me to create well, emmet snippits, which wasn't the behavior I was going for. I'm looking for a way to add the font family to the intellisense (such as adding "Inter, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" to the list of suggested fonts).

Is this possible?

Comment: simplest solution is to create your own `font-family` snippet and give it a prefix of `myfontfamily`, add your alternatives